# Pandas: Problem in Concatenation of three Data Frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am loading three.csv files into three different Pandas data frames. The number of rows in each file should be the same, but it is not. Sometimes one file contains four to five additional rows compared to another. Sometimes two files include two to three extra rows compared to one file. I'm concatenating all files row by row, so I'm removing these additional rows to make them the same length. I wrote the following code to accomplish this.

```
    df_ch = pd.read_csv("./file1.csv")
    df_wr = pd.read_csv("./file2.csv")
    df_an = pd.read_csv("./file3.csv")
    # here df_wr have less number of rows than df_ch and df_an, so dropping rows from other two frames (df_ch and df_an)
    df_ch.drop(df_ch.index[274299:274301], inplace=True)
    df_an.drop(df_an.index[274299], inplace=True)
```

I did it manually in the above code, and now I want to do it automatically. One method is to use if-else to check the length of all frames and make it equal to the shortest length frame. But I'm curious whether Pandas has a faster technique to compare these frames and delete the additional rows.

Comment: In general, the most robust way to do this is to have some field which is shared between all three files, which is used to match the rows together. This handles the data being out of order, and handles missing data in one of the files. This is called a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of way you can do:

In general,

```
#take the intersection of all the index: 
common = df1.index.intersection(df2.index).intersection(df3.index)

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1).reindex(common)
```

Or in your case, maybe just

```
max_rows = min(map(len, [df1,df2,df3]))
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1).iloc[:max_rows]
```

**Update**: best option should be `join`:

```
df1.join(df2, how='inner').join(df3, how='inner')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works and this one is `df1.join(df2, how='inner').join(df3, how='inner')` is best option I believe.

Comment: Huang one more question please: I had labels column in data frame, the values of that column is string like cat, dog, goat etc. I replaced with the numeric values like 0, 1, 2 .... Formally code is `df["labels"].replace("cat", value=0, inplace=True)`. Its worked but now I want to check that all the labels are correctly replace by number. Want to ensure that no string labels are not left there. So how should i use `assert` to rise the error if there is string than numeric number?

Comment: Check out [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html).